# How to minimize Kafka consumer's latency?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to develop a real time data streaming application with Kafka. Producers send message to broker which resides in different pc in same LAN. Then broker send message to consumer which also resides in different pc in same LAN. If producer,consumer and brokers are running on same pc no problem arrives. But in my scenario consumer's lag increases dramatically. On the other hand when new consumer running on broker machine it's lag value changes between 0 and 10. But remote consumer's lag values increases to 200 after 1 minute also it gets rarely messages like 10 messages between every 5 seconds.
In this scenario i have one consumer, one producer, one broker and one topic with 1 partition. What configurations options can i adjust to minimize latency?

consumer.config:

```
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.1.47:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = true
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = stream-app
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 1
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

and here producer.config:

```
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [192.168.1.47:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
```

consumer code:

```
public void startConsume() {
        int i=0;
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(10));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> cors : consumerRecords) {
                System.out.println(cors.key()+" ..... " +cors.value()+ " ..... " +i);
                i++;
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: With `max.poll.records = 1` your consumer is restricted to reading one record at a time. Could you try bumping it up to something larger (Kafka default is 500 btw).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also tried it but nothing change it shows very poor performance